# How to show that if y=f(x+a) is an even function where f(x)=(x-6)^2sin(bx) then a must be 6?

Tags: functions, trigonometry

With latex:

How to show that if $y=f(x+a)$ is an even function where $f(x)=(x-6)^2\sin(\omega x)$ then $a$ must be 6?

The original question was to solve for what $\omega$s are possible. And there was a step like this: since $y=f(x+a)$ is even, so is $y=(x+a-6)^2$ and $y=\sin(\omega x+\omega a)$. I'm confused by this step.

Answer (score 1):

We exclude the trivial case where $\omega=0$

Then, what makes it hard is that there is a $\sin$ term that changes the scale of the quadratic $(x+a-6)^2$, so we consider the case when $\sin$ is at its maximum.

If $a>6$, for every $x>0$, $(x+a-6)^2>(-x+a-6)^2$, pick an $x>0$ such that $\sin(\omega(x+a))$ is at maximum $1$, then clearly $f(x+a)>f(-x+a)$ making $y=f(x+a)$ not even.

For $a<6$, it is basically the same story.